# comprehension of str.translate() on both ordinary and unicode strings

Tags: python

```
strings = [word.translate(table) for word in strings]
```

`strings` has both ordinary and unicode characters, thus when it iterates an ordinary strings I get an error. Is there a concise way of making this code work as intended, or I have to write a function to check and execute the proper str.translate()?

Comment: Why are you using mixed strings in the first place?

Comment: why wouldnt you translate it all at once `" ".join(strings).translate(table).split()`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am parsing the contents of a webpage. Some of the strings have only ascii characters so I guess python reads them as ordinary, but some have utf-8 characters and thus come as unicode.

Comment: @Kei: what parser are you using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always work with *one* type of string; if your `str` values contain ASCII only, simply convert those to `unicode`; as converting `unicode` to `unicode` is a no-op you can use `unicode()` on both types:

```
strings = [unicode(word).translate(table) for word in strings]
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I was specifying the encoding to be utf-8, then when it iterated an utf-8 string I would get: `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`. Tried again right now without the "utf-8" and it worked. Why it works like that?

Comment: @Kei: without a codec the default is picked; for Python 2 that is `ASCII`.